# Pass data from child component to parent and back down

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, binding

Say I have a component that looks like this:

**parent.component.js**

```
...
template: `<div>
             <child-one value="value" callback="callback"></child-one>
             <child-two value="value"></child-two>
           </div>`,
controller: function() {
  this.callback = function(n) {
    this.value = n;
  }
}
...
```

Then the child components look like this:

**childOne.component.js**

```
...
bindings: {
  value: '<',
  callback: '<'
},
template: `<input type="text"
                  ng-model="$ctrl.value"
                  ng-change="$ctrl.callback($ctrl.value)"
           />`
...
```

**childTwo.component.js**

```
...
bindings: {
  value: '<'
},
template: `<div>{{$ctrl.value}}</div>`
...
```

(binding technique thanks to [krawaller](http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/dissecting-bindings-in-angularjs/))

I want the value that is set in `childOne` to go to `childTwo`. Updating the `value` in `childOne` does update the `value` in the `parent` but does not pass it down to `childTwo`.

Comment: The best way is to use service to share data.

Answer (score 1):

***Note:***
You are setting values in the **this** object. Not directly in the **$scope**.

Use $scope, instead of **this**

Modified code:

> parent.component.js

```
...
template: `<div>
             <child-one value="value" callback="callback"></child-one>
             <child-two value="value"></child-two>
           </div>`,
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.callback = function(n) {
    $scope.value = n;
    console.log($scope.value);
  }
}
...
```

If you want to write a code with **this** keyword, then use **controllerAs** syntax.

> Refer below code for **parent.component.js**

```
...
template: `<div>parent: {{vm.value}} <br/><div/>
         <div>
            <child-one value="vm.value" callback="vm.callback"></child-one>
            <child-two value="vm.value"></child-two>
         </div>`,
controller: function() {
  const vm = this;
  vm.callback = function(n) {
    vm.value = n;
    console.log(vm.value);

  }
},
controllerAs: "vm"
...
```

**Result:**
Updating the value in childOne will update the value in the parent as well as childTwo.

Comment: Okay so then when are you supposed to use `$scope` over `this`? From what I've found/learened, with `components` you use `this` as it creates an `isolated-scope`, unless you want to access `$watch`, `$digest`, `$emit` (at least per https://teamtreehouse.com/community/angularjs-controller-thismodel-vs-scopemodel)

Comment: For using $scope over this [refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Also, 
as per my point of view, "this" [Controller Ref] is also a variable which will be assign to $scope in the HTML.

You can have a look into the $scope parameter in details. You will get to know that "this" [controller ref] is assigned in the scope of that HTML itself.

So, no matter when to use $scope or this.
Just follow the conventions.
Thanks.